# Why does Merge ignore one specific shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, merge

I am working with ArcGIS 10.3.1.4959 (`License type: Advanced`), and am trying to merge 3 point shapefiles together using the `Data Management Tools -> General -> Merge` functionality from ArcToolbox.

Between the shapefiles the fields do not match. But what's important is that they share the same coordinate system and geometry, being all points.

When I apply the `Merge` tool, the final result is never consistent: sometimes it includes the last element of the 1st shapefile, and sometimes the 1st shapefile is not at all present. I always get all the elements in the last two shapefiles, however. All three shapefiles are within the same Geodatabase.

I have tried to use `Data Management Tools -> General -> Append` but I am forced to use the `NO_TEST` schema type, losing useful information.

**Why does this happen, and what can I do to walk around this obstacle?**

Comment: Please **edit** the question to specify the license level of Desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not clarify the reason why this problem occurred, but to advise on a  workaround that seemed to do the trick.

It consisted of:

1. Using `Data Management Tools -> General -> Merge` to merge together the 1st with the 2nd shapefile, so to create a "byproduct" shapefile;
2. Using `Data Management Tools -> General -> Merge` to merge the "byproduct" to the 3rd shapefile, so to obtain the *intended outcome*.

By simply counting the total number of points in the outcome, this seems to have worked.